# What is family-to-family citations and how is it different from patent-to-patent citations?

Tags: citation, statistics

I am working on Patent Ranking project where I need to consider patent citations as one of the metric.
I cant find the definition of family-to-family citations. And how is it different from patent-to-patent citations.

Answer (score 4):

When a patent cites a patent that's a patent-to-patent citation.

When a patent from the patent family (e.g. a [divisional application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisional_patent_application) or a continuation application) other than the patent itself cites a patent - that's a family citation, because the family cites the other patent.

As a side note, those citations normally include every citation made by the applicant, the examiner or a third party, so the meaningfulness differs.